# Mysql data to convert Array List

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, arraylist

I have result set from database like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [StartTime] => 2014-06-24 12:30:00
        [EndTime] => 2014-06-24 13:50:00
        [Date] => 2014-06-24
        [BookingId] => 2
        [TableId] => 39
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [StartTime] => 2014-06-24 13:50:00
        [EndTime] => 2014-06-24 16:20:00
        [Date] => 2014-06-24
        [BookingId] => 3
        [TableId] => 39
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [StartTime] => 2014-06-24 06:30:00
        [EndTime] => 2014-06-24 07:10:00
        [Date] => 2014-06-24
        [BookingId] => 4
        [TableId] => 37
    )


[7] => Array
    (
        [StartTime] => 2014-06-29 06:30:00
        [EndTime] => 2014-06-29 07:00:00
        [Date] => 2014-06-29
        [BookingId] => 9
        [TableId] => 39
    )


[9] => Array
    (
        [StartTime] => 2014-06-26 12:30:00
        [EndTime] => 2014-06-26 15:00:00
        [Date] => 2014-06-26
        [BookingId] => 11
        [TableId] => 37
    )
)
```

I Need the Array Like below Please Help Me,

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2014-06-24
        [Tables] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Array
                 (
                    [TableId] => 39
                    [Reservations] => Array
                    (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [BookingId] => 2
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [[BookingId] => 3
                                )
                    )
                )
                [1] => Array
                 (
                    [TableId] => 37
                    [Reservations] => Array
                    (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [BookingId] => 4
                                )

                    )
                )
            )   
        )



    [1] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2014-06-26
        [Tables] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Array
                 (
                    [TableId] => 37
                    [Reservations] => Array
                    (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [BookingId] => 11
                                )

                    )
                )

            )   
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2014-06-29
        [Tables] => Array
            (
                 [0] => Array
                 (
                    [TableId] => 39
                    [Reservations] => Array
                    (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [BookingId] => 9
                                )

                    )
                )

            )   
    )
)
```

I have Used The Following Code To Get The Result In CODEIGNITER Framework php ,

i have tried like this,,

function example(){

```
    $oldArray = $this->db->query("Select StartTime,EndTime,date(StartTime) as Date,BookingId,TableId from tblbooking")->result_array();



    foreach ($oldArray as $row){

        $data = $row['Date'];
        $newArray[$row['Date']][$row['TableId']][] = array('TableId' => $row['TableId'],'Date' => $row['Date'],'BookingId' => $row['BookingId']);

    }

    foreach($newArray as $index => $back){

            foreach($back as $index2 => $back2){
                $t3[] = array( 'Date' => $index,'Tables' => $back);
            }
    }

    print_r($t3);
}
```

but i am unable to get the above array list
so please help me

Comment: Have you tried to do anything?

Comment: yes i have tried but i got nothing,actually i need to convert the final result into json

Comment: You have to show what you've tried (code)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but something like this.

First, sort the array into date order, and tableid order within date (you could probably do this in the SQL query that gets the data for the array).

Then loop through keeping track of changes in the date / table to set the counter for date / table.

```
<?php

$Out = array();
$prev_date = '';
$prev_table = '';
$day = -1;
$table = -1;

// Sort the array into date order, and table order within date
usort($some_array, "cmp");

foreach($some_array AS $some_array_item)
{
    if ($some_array_item['Date'] != $prev_date)
    {
        $day++;
        $Out[$day] = array();
        $Out[$day]['Date'] = $some_array_item['Date'];
        $Out[$day]['Tables'] = array();
        $table = -1;
        $prev_date = $some_array_item['Date'];
        $prev_table = '';
    }
    if ($some_array_item['TableId'] != $prev_table)
    {
        $table++;
        $Out[$day]['Tables'][$table]['TableId'] = $some_array_item['TableId'];
        $Out[$day]['Tables'][$table]['Reservations'] = array();
        $prev_table = $some_array_item['TableId'];
    }
    $Out[$day]['Tables'][$table]['Reservations'][] = array('BookingId'=>$some_array_item['BookingId']);
}

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['Date'] == $b['Date']) 
    {
        if ($a['Date']['TableId'] == $b['Date']['TableId']) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['Date']['TableId'] < $b['Date']['TableId']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ($a['Date'] < $b['Date']) ? -1 : 1;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer its helped me alot,its saved me.
THANKS 
THANKS